# Integration using trapezoid rule

Tags: integration

I am trying to solve this expression using trapeze rule. 
$$\int_0^1(1+x)\ln^2(1+x)dx$$

So at the beginning I am dividing into five equal parts:

```
0-0.2, 0.2-0.4, 0.4-0.6, 0.6-0.8, 0.8-1
```

After that I calculate the value for those points using my `f(x)` expression.

```
f(x) = (1 + x)ln^2(1+x)
f(0) = (1 + 0)ln^2(1+0) = 0
f(0.2) = (1 + 0.2)ln^2(1+0.2) = 0.0398
f(0.4) = (1 + 0.4)ln^2(1+0.4) = 0.1584
f(0.6) = (1 + 0.6)ln^2(1+0.6) = 0.3534
f(0.8) = (1 + 0.8)ln^2(1+0.8) = 0.6218
f(1) = (1 + 1)ln^2(1+1) = 0.9609
```

Now I am using this [pattern](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OH5Wl.png) to calculate the approximate value of the integral.

```
=0.2*(0.9609/2+0.0398+0.1584+0.3534+0.6218) = 0.3307
```

I wanted to check if value i got is correct, so i visited Wolfarm Alpha. I put there my expression and I got `2.57406` resault.

Which result is correct?

Comment: You're doing something wrong with Wolfram Alpha: the integrand is always less than 2 so the answer can't exceed 2.

Comment: I would put the 0/2 in there, too, to make it clearer.